# Delete last dynamically created html row created jquery

Tags: jquery

I created a row in side a table dynamically

```
var index = 1;

$("#add_field").click(function(){

var new_field = '<tr><th style="text-align: left;">Customer '+index+'</th><td><input type="text" id="customer'+index+'" name="customer'+index+'" maxlength="50"></td><th style="text-align: left;">Phone</th><td><input type="text" id="customerphone'+index+'" name="customerphone'+index+'" maxlength="14"></td><th style="text-align: left;">Email</th><td><input type="text" id="customeremail'+index+'" name="customeremail'+index+'" maxlength="100"></td></tr>';

$("#customerFormTable").append(new_field); });
```

html

```
<div id="add_field">Click here to add more rows </div>
```

How do I now create a delete - to delete last row I just created

```
<div id="delete_row">Click here to delete last row created </div>

$("#delete_row").click(function(){  ??????
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#customerFormTable tr:last").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Give Id to element TR based on that delete that particular row

```
$("#trid").remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for both answers.  They helped me get it done.  here is what I wrote 

First when I created the tr dynamically I gave it the id

    <tr id="new'+index+'">

Then for the remove

    $("#remove_field").click(function(){
 index--;
 $("#new"+index).remove();
           });

All works exactly how I wanted it thanks.